# How can I add the value from button to the text box by click?

Tags: javascript, button, input, event-listener

```js
const button = document.getElementById('#1');
button.addEventListener('click', e=>{
e.preventDefault()
document.getElementByName('field).innerText = 1;
})
```

```html
 <div class="header">
            <input type="text" name="field" id="field">
        </div>
      




<div class="btn"><input type="button" id="1" class="button" value="1"></div>
            <div class="btn"><input type="button" id="2" class="button" value="2"></div>
            <div class="btn"><input type="button" id="3" class="button" value="3"></div>
```

when I click on the button nothing be occur and how can I manage that.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to learn here. `getElementById` takes a string with no `#` as an argument. You also had a typo in your `getElementByName('field)` (missing single quote). Additionally, there isn't a `getElementByName` - it would be `getElementsByName` (plural). Finally, you want to apply the same listener to all buttons of a certain class, so you can gather them up (I used `document.querySelectorAll('.button')` but `getElementsByName("button")` would work as well). Once you have that collection, iterate through it to set the event listener.

Lastly when you want to change the text in an input tag, you do it through the `value`, not the `innterText`. `innerText` is used for non-form HTML elements

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const field = document.querySelector('[name=field]');
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  let f = field.value.trim()? field.value.trim().split(",") : [];
  f.push(e.target.value);
  field.value = f.join(",")
}))
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <input type="text" name="field" id="field">
</div>
<div class="btn"><input type="button" id="1" class="button" value="1"></div>
<div class="btn"><input type="button" id="2" class="button" value="2"></div>
<div class="btn"><input type="button" id="3" class="button" value="3"></div>
```

Comment: tnx bro but it does not work , nothing be change in text box.

Comment: it does work in the snippet above right? It does for me

Comment: I got another problem, when I click twice it mean one time to one and another time on another button the text box clear the prior text can I join them without any trouble. thanks

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to allow you to keep adding to the input - is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to get the value of a DOM element, you need to get the element reference and then use the `value` property. For example:

`const buttonValue = document.getElementById('submit').value;`

When using `getElementById` you don't need to use `#1`, just `1` would be enough. Also, `getElementByName` doesn't seem to be a proper DOM manipulation function, the alternative is `getElementsByName` (gets list of all elements with specified name).

Keeping this in mind, see code below:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('1');

button.addEventListener('click', e=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('field').value = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
  <div class="header">
     <input type="text" name="field" id="field">
 </div>
      
 <div class="btn">
     <input type="button" id="1" class="button" value="1"> 
 </div>
            <div class="btn"><input type="button" id="2" class="button" value="2"></div>
            <div class="btn"><input type="button" id="3" class="button" value="3"></div>
```